# return confrm delay problem

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, google-chrome

For starters, here is my markup:

```
<form action="/People/_Delete/AUG0003/10?searchType=IdentityCode&amp;Filter=a&amp;searchOption=StartsWith" method="post" onsubmit="return confirm(&#39;Are you sure you want to delete AUG0003?&#39;)">
  <input id="rowcount" type="hidden" value="10" />
  <button alt="Delete" class="g-button user_delete.png" title="Delete AUG0003" type="submit" value="Delete"></button>
</form>
```

When, i press the button, i receive the confirmation dialog, after i press OK, there is a 2-3 second delay before anything happens.

If i remove the confirmation, it happens fast and instantaneously.

Has anyone encountered this before? It is a real pain.

Thanks,

Nick

Comment: What browser are we talking about, or does all browser have the lag you are talking about?

Comment: Sorry, this appears to be a Chrome issue.
All other browsers seem to process this fine :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested this behaviour in Chromium ("Chrome"), and cannot reproduce your issue. JavaScript functions properly:

```
<script>var time=0;</script> 
<form action="javascript:alert((new Date).getTime()-time)" method="post" onsubmit="return confirm(&#39;Are you sure you want to delete AUG0003?&#39;)&&(time=(new Date).getTime())">
  <input id="rowcount" type="hidden" value="10" />
  <button alt="Delete" class="g-button user_delete.png" title="Delete AUG0003" type="submit" value="Delete"></button>
</form>
```

(Link: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eYuwN/show/))
When I hit the button, an alert box appears. This alert box shows the delayed time between `return confirm("")`, and the following of the `action` targer. I have hit the button multiple times, each time getting `0` (indicating that the issue is not caused by the use of `onsubmit`.

The "delay" is very likely caused by coincidence, impatience or a server-side issue.

Comment: Mine doesn't always return a 0, more than not, it returns a 1, sometimes a 2.

Is there a reason for this?

Comment: This can't be a server side issue, it works perfectly fine in all other browsers! :/

Comment: 1-2 milliseconds. That's still not a noticeable delay. You've just proved that the issue doesn't have a cause between `submit` and `action`.